# Why does the energy level (221) come before (311) for a particle in a 3 dimensional box?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

[image]

As per my understanding the ground state for a particle in 3d box is (1,1,1) and consequently the first excited state is (2,1,1);(1,2,1);(1,1,2). What is the principle behind having the energy levels (3,1,1) and its degenerates after (2,2,1) and it's degenerates and not (2,2,2) ?

Comment: States are listed in ascending energy, see column 1 of the table. (222) has higher energy than (221).

Answer (score 2):

The energy levels of a [particle in a cubic box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box#Higher-dimensional_boxes)
(with side length $L$ in all $3$ directions) are
$$E_{n_xn_yn_z}=\frac{(n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)\pi^2\hbar ^2}{2mL^2}$$
or using $E_1=\frac{\pi^2\hbar ^2}{2mL^2}$
$$E_{n_xn_yn_z}=(n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)E_1$$
This formula reproduces the values in the left-most column of
the table in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula $E_{n_x n_y n_z}= \frac{\hbar^2 \pi^2}{2 m L^2} (n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2)$ with $(n_x, n_y, n_z) \in {\mathbf N}^3$ answers your questions.